# What is the difference between "?:" and ":" symbols in Typescript

Tags: typescript2.0

In the below interface declration in TypeScript language
"**?:**" and "**:**" symbol is used , i am not able to understand the difference between both the symbol. I am new to Typescript So please help me.

```
interface SquareConfig {
    color?: string;
    width: number
}
```

Comment: It means that the color field is optional, and would not throw errors if left out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you declare a property in the interface using `?:`, that means that property is optional. When you assign that interface to a variable it's not mandatory to assign value to that property.

Eg -

```
export interface myClass {
    name: string,
    age?: string
}
```

In the component, you have to assign a value to `name` property but since the `age` property is optional it's not required

```
  values: myClass = {
    name: 'john'
    // age field is not required
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

```
interface SquareConfig {
    color?: string;
    width: number
}
```

Means that `color` is an optional property.

```
let x: SquareConfig = {
    // allowed to omit color without getting a compilation error
    width: 10
}
```